# If a mole digs a hole in the football field

Tags: football

I saw a weird dream that in a football, a mole dug a big hole just under the penalty spot and none could kick the penalty, as the ball would fell under the ground. Do football rules say anything about such a weird situation?

Comment: If conditions of the field were this bad (i.e., players can be severely injured due to issues with pitch), the game would not be started to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does football rules says anything about such a weird situation?

Perhaps unsurprisingly, no!

Should this actually happen, the ground staff would most likely remedy the situation with earth, sand and turf, following up by repainting the spot.

In a penalty shootout, and where the ground staff could not fix the hole, I would imagine that the referee would have the penalties taken at the opposite end of the pitch.

Comment: If the hole could not be fixed, the game would not be played due to unsafe conditions!

Answer (score 1):

If the hole could not be fixed, the game would not be played due to unsafe conditions!

It is a nice idea for a quirky film but IRL sense would prevail and the match would be moved.